# Codeigniter MySQL dataset not filtered

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatable

I have a simple stores program developed using Codeigniter. Following are the main tables.

## store_item

```
+---------+----------------+---------------+--------+
| item_id |   item_name    | item_sub_type | status |
+---------+----------------+---------------+--------+
|       1 | A4             |           100 |      1 |
|       2 | A5             |           100 |      1 |
|       3 | CFL Bulb 15W   |           102 |      1 |
|       4 | Toilet Cleaner |           102 |      1 |
+---------+----------------+---------------+--------+
```

## item_sub_type

```
+-------------+---------------+-----+--------+
| sub_type_id | sub_type_name | cat | status |
+-------------+---------------+-----+--------+
|         100 | Stationary    | S   |      1 |
|         101 | Electric Item | S   |      1 |
|         102 | Consumable    | S   |      1 |
|         103 | Vehicle Spare | V   |      1 |
+-------------+---------------+-----+--------+
```

## store_update_stock

```
+-----------------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------+
| update_stock_id | purchased_date | order_status | transfer_status | status |
+-----------------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------+
|               1 | 2019-10-01     | purchase     | approved        |      1 |
|               2 | 2019-10-02     | purchase     | approved        |      1 |
|               3 | 2019-10-03     | issue        | approved        |      1 |
+-----------------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------+
```

## store_update_stock_details

```
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+------------+--------+
| update_stock_details_id | update_stock_id | item | qty | unit_price | status |
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+------------+--------+
|                       1 |               1 |    1 |  10 |     450.00 |      1 |
|                       2 |               1 |    2 |   5 |     375.00 |      1 |
|                       3 |               2 |    1 |  20 |     450.00 |      1 |
|                       4 |               2 |    3 | 100 |     850.00 |      1 |
|                       5 |               2 |    4 |  15 |     125.00 |      1 |
|                       6 |               3 |    1 | -15 |     450.00 |      1 |
|                       7 |               3 |    3 | -10 |     850.00 |      1 |
|                       8 |               3 |    4 |  -2 |     125.00 |      1 |
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+------------+--------+
```

Issued quantities in the store_update_stock_details table are denoted with minus (-).

I tried to get filtered item summary by the item & item_sub_type

## Reports Controller

```
public function stockReport()
    {
        $bc = array(array('link' => '#', 'page' => 'Stationary Stock Report'));
        $meta = array('page_title' => 'Stationary Stock Report', 'bc' => $bc);
        $where = NULL;
        if ($this->input->post('item')) {
            $item = $this->input->post('item');

            $where .= " AND store_item.item_id = '$item' ";

        } else {
            $item = NULL;
        }

        $where = NULL;
        if ($this->input->post('subType')) {
            $subType = $this->input->post('subType');
            $where .= " AND store_sub_type.sub_type_id = '$subType' ";
        } else {
            $subType = NULL;
        }

        $this->data['item'] = $this->Item_Model->getItem();        
        $this->data['subType'] = $this->Item_Model->getSubType();
        $this->data['summary'] = $this->Report_model->stockSummary($where);    
        $this->render('reports/stockReport', $meta, $this->data);
    }
```

## Item_model

```
function getItem()
    {
        $q = $this->db->get_where('store_item', array('status' => '1'));
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $q->result();
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    function getSubType()
    {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from('store_sub_type');        
        $this->db->where("status=1 and cat='S'  ");       
        $this->db->order_by('sub_type_id');
        $q1 = $this->db->get();
        if ($q1->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $q1->result();
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

## Report_model

```
function stockSummary($where){
    $q = $this->db->query("
    select
    item_id,
    item_name,
    unit_price,
    sub_type_id,
    ( SELECT @stock := sum(ifnull(qty,0)) AS qty FROM store_update_stock_details de2 
    JOIN store_update_stock st2 ON de2.update_stock_id=st2.update_stock_id 

    RIGHT JOIN store_item item2 ON de2.item=item2.item_id WHERE de2.status = 1 and 
    st2.transfer_status = 'Approved'  AND tmp.item_id = item2.item_id GROUP BY item2.item_id) as cur_stock,

    SUM(purchase) as purchase,
    SUM(issues) as issues

    FROM (
    SELECT

    item_name,
    item_id,
    unit_price,
    store_sub_type.sub_type_id,

    CASE WHEN  order_status = 'purchase' THEN  qty else 0  end as purchase , 
    CASE WHEN  order_status ='issue' and transfer_status='Issued' THEN  qty else 0  end as issues , 
    CASE WHEN  store_update_stock.status != 0 and transfer_status !='Pending' and transfer_status !='Recomended' THEN  qty else 0  
    end as balance 
    from store_update_stock
    join store_update_stock_details on store_update_stock.update_stock_id=store_update_stock_details.update_stock_id
    join store_item on store_update_stock_details.item=store_item.item_id
    join store_sub_type on store_sub_type.sub_type_name=store_item.item_sub_type

    where store_update_stock.status=1 $where    
    )tmp
    group by item_id, unit_price

    ");
```

## stockReport View

```
<style>
    .group {
        background: #FFAAAA !important;
        color: #009966; 
    }

     .table > tbody > tr > th,  .table > tbody > tr > td{
        font-size: 13px;
    }

</style>
<div class="box box-info">
    <div class="box box-info collapsed-box">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">List of Stationary / Consumables & Electical Items</h3>

            <div class="box-tools pull-right">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" style="font-size: 16px;" data-widget="collapse"><i
                            class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </button>

            </div>
            <!-- /.box-tools -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body" style="display: block">
            <form action="<?= site_url('reports/stockReport') ?>" method="post">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group"><label>Item</label>
                            <select name="item" id="item" class="form-control select2">
                                <option value="">Select Item</option>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($item as $row){
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?=$row->item_id?>"><?=$row->item_name?></option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group"><label>Item Sub Type</label>
                            <select name="subType" id="subType" class="form-control select2">
                                <option value="">Select Item Sub Type</option>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($subType as $row){
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?=$row->sub_type_id?>"><?=$row->sub_type_name?></option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="Search"
                                   class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
    </div>


    <div class="box-body">
        <!--<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="$"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Print</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>-->


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="printEl('datatable','Item List')">
                        <i class="fa fa-print "></i> Print
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive" id="datatable">
                <table id="ExData" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
                       class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped reports-table">
                    <thead id="th">
                    <tr class="" style="background-color: #ff3399 !important;">

                        <th >In Num</th>
                        <th >Item ID</th>
                        <th >Item Name</th>
                        <th >Item Sub Type</th>
                        <th class="text-center">p_qty</th>
                        <th class="text-center">is_qty </th>
                        <th class="text-center">balance </th>

                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    <?php
                    $c = 0;
                    $totalPurchase=0;
                    $totalIssues=0;

                    if(!empty($summary)) {
                        foreach ($summary as $row) {

                            $totalPurchase = $totalPurchase + $row->purchase;
                            $totalIssues = $totalIssues + $row->issues;
                            $totalBalance += $row->unit_price*($row->purchase - (-1) * $row->issues);
                            $c++;
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?= $c ?></td>
                                <td><?= $row->item_id ?></td>
                                <td><?= $row->item_name ?></td>
                                <td><?= $row->sub_type_id ?></td>
                                <td class="text-right"><?= $row->purchase+0 ?></td>
                                <td class="text-right"><?= ((-1) * $row->issues)+0 ?></td>
                                <td class="text-right"><?= $row->purchase - (-1) * $row->issues  ?></td>

                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }

                        ?>
                        </tr>

                        <?php
                    }else{
                        echo "<tr><td colspan='6'>No Data Available</td></tr>";
                    }
                    ?>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--end of add-->
<script>
    function printEl($el, title, $json, $th, $pdf) {
        var table = "";
        if ($json) {
            table += '<table id="SLData" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">' +
                '<thead><tr>';
            $($th).each(function (i, el) {
                table += $th[i];
            });
            table += "</tr></thead><tbody>";

            $($json).each(function (i, el) {
                table += '<tr>';
                $(el).each(function (j, el2) {
                    table += '<td>' + el[j] + '</td>';
                });
                table += '</tr>';

            });
            table += "</tbody></table>";
        }
        var divToPrint = (table) ? table : document.getElementById($el).innerHTML;
        var head = $('head').html(),
            title = (title) ? '<h3 style="background-color: #e0ebff; font-size:20px;padding: 5px;color: #191919; font-family: \'Ubuntu\', sans-serif !important;font-weight: bold;" align="center"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/dist/img/logo-mini.png">' + 'Item list' + '</h3>' : '';
        if (!$pdf) {
            var printWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');
            printWin.document.open();
            printWin.document.write('<html>' + head + '<body style="background: #ffffff;" onload="window.print();">' + title + divToPrint + '</body></html>');
            printWin.document.close();
            setTimeout(function () {
                printWin.close();
//                $("#INV_datatable th:last-child, #INV_datatable td:last-child").show();
            }, 500);
        }
    }

</script>
```

The above tables & codes generate the following output correctly

```
+---------+----------------+---------------+-------+--------+---------+
| item_id |   item_name    | item_sub_type | p_qty | is_qty | balance |
+---------+----------------+---------------+-------+--------+---------+
|       1 | A4             | Stationary    |    30 |     15 |      15 |
|       2 | A5             | Stationary    |     5 |      0 |       5 |
|       3 | CFL Bulb 15W   | Consumable    |   100 |     10 |      90 |
|       4 | Toilet Cleaner | Consumable    |    15 |      2 |      13 |
+---------+----------------+---------------+-------+--------+---------+
```

Then I need to filter this report by the item_name & item_sub_type as follows

```
+---------+-----------+---------------+-------+--------+---------+
| item_id | item_name | item_sub_type | p_qty | is_qty | balance |
+---------+-----------+---------------+-------+--------+---------+
|       1 | A4        | Stationary    |    30 |     15 |      15 |
|       2 | A5        | Stationary    |     5 |      0 |       5 |
+---------+-----------+---------------+-------+--------+---------+

+---------+----------------+---------------+-------+--------+---------+
| item_id |   item_name    | item_sub_type | p_qty | is_qty | balance |
+---------+----------------+---------------+-------+--------+---------+
|       3 | CFL Bulb 15W   | Consumable    |   100 |     10 |      90 |
|       4 | Toilet Cleaner | Consumable    |    15 |      2 |      13 |
+---------+----------------+---------------+-------+--------+---------+
```

But the filters (item_name & item_sub_type) didn't filter records correctly. I think i made the codes for filters well. What may be going wrong ?

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set $where = NULL 2 times,
so its removing 1st condition from the where clause,

just remove the 2nd $where= NULL, it will be fine.

```
public function stockReport()
{
    $bc = array(array('link' => '#', 'page' => 'Stationary Stock Report'));
    $meta = array('page_title' => 'Stationary Stock Report', 'bc' => $bc);
    $where = NULL; // 1st time
    if ($this->input->post('item')) {
        $item = $this->input->post('item');

        $where .= " AND store_item.item_id = '$item' ";

    } else {
        $item = NULL;
    }

    // $where = NULL; // remove this, as you are reseting $where to NULL, so 1st condition is gone.
    if ($this->input->post('subType')) {
        $subType = $this->input->post('subType');
        $where .= " AND store_sub_type.sub_type_id = '$subType' ";
    } else {
        $subType = NULL;
    }

    $this->data['item'] = $this->Item_Model->getItem();        
    $this->data['subType'] = $this->Item_Model->getSubType();
    $this->data['summary'] = $this->Report_model->stockSummary($where);    
    $this->render('reports/stockReport', $meta, $this->data);
}
```